# Dynamic table partitioning in postgres

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I was looking up ways to have postgres partition data into tables based on timestamp for example, but without having to add the relevant child tables manually. I saw this blog post that does just that

https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/scaling-postgresql-performance-table-partitioning

but I'm dubious about the idea of creating tables based on string concatenation and checking the pg_catalog. Is this a reasonable idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[pg_partman](https://github.com/keithf4/pg_partman) is an extension created specifically to manage the complexity of partition management. I haven't used this extension, but I've used others by the same author and they are generally of excellent quality.