# pg_partman extension for Partitioning Tables on PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning

It's my first question here, after have been reading for years, so be nice with me please.

I am migrating my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. There's tables in my MySQL  database that might have large amount of data and I used MySQL ranged partitioning according to timestamp.

I find that PostgreSQL partitions is not that simple to configure and maintain. 
[pg_partman extension](https://github.com/keithf4/pg_partman) is recommended in [the answer for similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734610/dynamic-table-partitioning-in-postgres/17734697#17734697).
But pg_partman is mentioned only in this answer in stackoverflow.

I want to know more about usage and stability of this extension before using it on my project or if there's other recommended way to implement partitioning (or kind of) in PostgreSQL.

Comment: pg_partman works fine when you need partitioning. But do you really need it? How many records does a large table have?

Comment: I'm using partitioning for 2 reasons: 
1.large amount of data in some environments (millions of records or more according to configured settings)
2. removing old records without locking the table for long time.

Comment: For "millions of rows" partitioning is usually not really necessary - good indexes will get you a long way. When you run a `delete` the table is not locked at all. You can continue to select, insert and update rows in that table without problems (as long as you don't insert or update PK values that you are deleting at the same time).

Comment: Records are deleted according to timestamp column and it's part of the PKs.

Comment: We partition by month and have about 500 million records per month. For a couple of million records I wouldn't use partitioning. When we delete data, we drop an entire table partition, no DELETE or TRUNCATE needed.

Comment: Thanks, i will do some tests for verifying the need of partitioning. I'm going to insert and select records into/from my tables (timestamp is part of PK columns) and query concurrently a delete of records that less than a specific timestamp. Thanks again

Comment: @Biano Did you eventually decide to partition & if so did you end up using pg_partman? If so please share your feedback on the same..i understand with recent improvements w.r.t partitioning in postgres the need for this has kind of reduced a little bit...but nevertheless if you do have an experience/feedback, i would like to hear about it.